# Unable to populate chained dropdown list with Ajax and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I'm new to Ajax, and programming in general, and I am currently in the midst of learning as I go.

**My Goal**

I am currently trying to create a chained dropdown list with the first dropdown populating itself from my database, and the second dropdown populating itself based on the user's selection in the first dropdown.

**My code(Form Page)**

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
  if(@$_SESSION['Auth']!=="Yes") {
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page.Please click <a href='Login.php'>here</a> to login.";
    exit();
  }
?>
<?PHP
  //Processing Code goes here
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function getcategory() {
      var xmlhttp;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          alert("This is an alert 1");
          document.getElementById("category").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      alert("This is an alert 2");
      xmlhttp.open("GET","AddItemCat.php","true");
      alert("This is an alert 3");
      xmlhttp.send();
      alert("This is an alert 4");
    }
    function getsubcategory(cat) {
      var xmlhttp;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","AddItemSubCat.php?cat="+cat,"true");
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="additem" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Select Category: </td>
      <td><script>alert("This is an alert 5");</script>
        <select id="category" onclick="getcategory()">
          <script>alert("This is an alert 6");</script>
          <option id="cat"value=""></option>
          <script>alert("This is an alert 7");</script>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Select SubCategory</td>
      <td>
        <select id="subcat" onclick="getsubcategory(cat)">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Code(AddItemCat.php)**

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
  if(@$_SESSION['Auth']!=="Yes") {
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page.Please click <a href='Login.php'>here</a> to login.";
    exit();
  }
?>
<?PHP
  if(@$_SESSION['Auth']=="Yes" && @$_SESSION['Type']=="Admin") {
    include("cxn.inc");
    $userid=$_SESSION['UserId']
    $branchid=0;
    $getcat="SELECT * FROM `Categories` WHERE `Business`=$userid AND Branch=$branchid";
    $runcat=mysqli_query($cxn,$getcat) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runcat)) {
      $cat=$row['Category'];
      echo"<option value=$cat>$cat</option>";
    }
  }
?>
```

**My code(AddItemSubCat.php)**

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
  if(@$_SESSION['Auth']!=="Yes") {
    echo"You are not authorised to view this page.Please click <a href='Login.php'>here</a> to login.";
    exit();
  }
?>

<?PHP
  if(@$_SESSION['Auth']=="Yes" && @$_SESSION['Type']=="Admin") {
    include("cxn.inc");
    //Gets the category parameter passed from the URL
    $cat=$_GET['cat'];
    $userid=$_SESSION['UserId']
    $branchid=0;
    $getsub="SELECT * FROM `SubCategories` WHERE `Business`=$userid AND Branch=$branchid && Category==$cat";
    $runsub=mysqli_query($cxn,$getsub) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runsub)) {
      $sub=$row['Category'];
      echo"<option value=$sub>$sub</option>";
    }
  }
?>
```

**Errors(Or rather Lack of errors)**

Both my Category and SubCategory dropdown lists are empty and nothing is showing up, and I can't see what it is exactly WTF it is that I've done wrong. Could anyone kindly point out my errors and tell me how to correct them and improve? I've been looking at the screen for 2 hours not and i'm no closer to figuring out my error as i'm not getting ANYTHING at all( no error messages), just a table with the 2 dropdown boxes that are totally empty.

Thanks!

PS: My ultimate aim is to create a form like the one used in online stores where the user can upload an item, together with accompanying pictures. I've yet to add the rest of the form as there is no point in it since my dropboxes are not working.

EDIT: Added a table to the form page that was missing before.No visible changes to the results and am still unable to get the code working.

EDIT 2:Added various alerts to the code.Only the alerts 5,6 and 7 are working and pop out when i load the page.The alerts in the javascript are not working, so the issue obviously lies within the javascript function, though i still cant see what the error is.

Comment: I this would be very easy to do using jQuery AJAX. Have you considered that?

Comment: The problem here is that i've only just started on Javascript, and have to touch on jquery as i thought i would be a good idea to at least get a grasp on javascript and AJAX before moving on to jquery.

Comment: that makes sense. Although I would say you can learn jQuery and javascript pretty much independently these days. Look at this tutorial: http://www.blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes-using-php-mysql-ajax/ see if this is something that you are trying to implement. Its a good idea to learn something from scratch but this is not how javascript functionality is implemented these days since JS libraries like jQuery take care of that part rather efficiently.

Comment: Try some alerts, e.g. after xmlhttp.readyState is 4

Comment: @ThomasLeu i've added some alerts to the code, i've edited my post to contain the results.Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend 2 changes -

1.Load your Category select options on page load, instead of using `onclick`.
-Add `onload="getcategory()"` to your body tag.

2.Load your SubCategory select options on change of Category.
-Add `onchange="getsubcategory(this)"` to your `<select id="category">`, and remove the `onclick="getsubcategory(cat)"` from your `<select id="subcat" >`
-Then use `var catval = cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].value;` in your `getsubcategory()` to get the selected value.

It would now look like -

```
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    function getcategory() {
      var xmlhttp;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("category").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","AddItemCat.php","true");
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function getsubcategory(cat) {
      var xmlhttp;
      var catval = cat.options[cat.selectedIndex].value;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        //code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","AddItemSubCat.php?cat="+catval,"true");
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="getcategory()">
  <form action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" name="additem" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Select Category: </td>
        <select id="category" onchange="getsubcategory(this)">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Select SubCategory</td>
      <td>
        <select id="subcat">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works!! I.Love.You. On another note, Is there any rationale/advantage for using onload in the <body> tag instead of using a onClick/onChange in the <select> itself? I suppose the only difference is that with the onload, when the user is directed to this page, the values are already loaded and displayed for him to choose from? It so, why not make the getcategory function synchronous instead of asynchronous? I could just populate the first dropdown list with a php query?